# combo box c# - How do I get rid of the first null in the combo list

Tags: c#, combobox

I can't find this anywhere.  It seems like everyone is trying to get a null at the very first of the list, but I want the opposite.  I don't want a null as an option in my combobox list.  How do i get rid of it.

```
foreach (String item in comboFieldList)
{
    fieldBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't get null at the start of the list unless I add it. Who is getting null? Who is trying to get null? And can you elaborate on the details?

Comment: What is 'a null' in terms of ComboBox `ListItems` and if you don't want one, simply don't add one?

Comment: Can you add some context to the code?

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Comment: adding to what @Widor said - do you mean null or an empty string? What creates the entries in **comboFieldList**?  If you don't want a null/empty string then the function that creates the entries for comboFieldList shouldn't add one.

Comment: Jay has answered the question below.  I did not show more code, because I didn't know what was needed to be shown.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Duy - if that answers your question, please accept Jay's answer by checking it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you've added your items to the `ComboBox`, set the `SelectedItem` to be the first item.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a null unless you add one specifically.

Maybe you are not informing the combo box to select the first item in the list after you have populated it?

After you have populated it, check it has values in and if so select the first index.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, Your not populating your combo box correctly. You need to set the display member :-

combobox1.Datasource = dataTable1;
combobox1.DisplayMember = "Column1";